# sharing printer and cd-rom via local network

Tags: networking, printing, file-sharing

I have to share cd-rom and printer to network which contains windows and linux machines. For this solve I have got: a rpi 3 b+, hp deskjet 2520hc printer and cd-rom reader/writer (transcend).

Comment: Plug each of your devices into your ethernet network and follow  each manufacturers instructions.  For Raspberry Pi, search "How do I get Raspberry Pi on my network?". In general, start with wired connections before attempting wifi.

Comment: cd-rom reader is a basic reader with usb connection which don't have network functions

Answer (score 1):

Install the samba server:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install samba
```

It description (`apt show samba`) says:

> SMB/CIFS file, print, and login server for Unix
>   Samba is an implementation of the SMB/CIFS protocol for Unix systems, providing support for cross-platform file and printer sharing with Microsoft Windows, OS X, and other Unix systems.

Edit `/etc/smb.conf` and configure the server to your needs. There are some examples in it and you get tons of information for this on the internet.

To connect a linux client to a smb share you need *smbclient* and/or *cifs-utils*.